# Error while fetching 1.7 million data from snowflake to a csv file

Tags: pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a case where I have to fetch 1.7 million records from a snowflake table and push it to CSV.

But I am getting the following error:

```
File "D:\Cloud\call_test.py", line 20, in
snowflakeConnect.export_to_csv(query, path_to_csv)
File "D:\Cloud\snowflake_to_dataframe.py", line 28, in export_to_csv
df = self._cursor.fetch_pandas_all()
File "C:\AMi-space\airflow\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\cursor.py", line 855, in fetch_pandas_all
return self._result._fetch_pandas_all(**kwargs)
File "src\snowflake\connector\arrow_result.pyx", line 259, in snowflake.connector.arrow_result.ArrowResult._fetch_pandas_all
File "pyarrow\array.pxi", line 751, in pyarrow.lib._PandasConvertible.to_pandas
File "pyarrow\table.pxi", line 1668, in pyarrow.lib.Table._to_pandas
File "C:\AMi-space\airflow\venv\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\pandas_compat.py", line 792, in table_to_blockmanager
blocks = _table_to_blocks(options, table, categories, ext_columns_dtypes)
File "C:\AMi-space\airflow\venv\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\pandas_compat.py", line 1131, in _table_to_blocks
result = pa.lib.table_to_blocks(options, block_table, categories,
File "pyarrow\table.pxi", line 1117, in pyarrow.lib.table_to_blocks
File "pyarrow\error.pxi", line 116, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
pyarrow.lib.ArrowException: Unknown error: Wrapping FEBRAMAT Federa��o Brasileira De Redes failed
```

Here is the code which I am trying:

```
class ExportToCsv:
    _cursor = None

    def __init__(self, account, user, password, role, warehouse):

        connection = sfc.connect(
            account=account,
            user=user,
            password=password,
            role=role,
            warehouse=warehouse
        )
        print("Connecting to snowflake.....")
        self._cursor = connection.cursor()

    def export_to_csv(self, query, path_to_csv):
        try:
            query = "{}".format(query)
            
            self._cursor.execute(query)

            df = self._cursor.fetch_pandas_all()

            path_to_csv = "{}".format(path_to_csv)

            df.to_csv(path_to_csv, index=False)
        finally:
            self._cursor.close()
```

It working fine till fetching 100,000 rows. But after that it's breaking

Comment: If you are writing a 1.7M row results into CSV file/s, why not just tell snowflake to write to S3 (or your platforms storage) and then just move/copy the file/s via python.

Comment: That's the call management has to take. For now, this is what I have been given to work on.

Comment: hmm, management should say "there is a problem, try fix it" and development should say "method one didn't work, now on to method two"

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim hahaha, wish I could say like this to the management